# bean instantiation and dependency injection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm new to Spring and I'm trying to understand what happens during runtime. I know that using dependency injection (for example the Setter injection) in Spring enables the Spring container to create these beans or set values to the beans.

However, is this bean creation occurring at runtime or at compile time? If you could give me a link that explains this step by step it'll be really helpful too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All bean creation and injection happens at runtime. Spring uses reflection to find types and their methods to do this.

It's explained in detail in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/). See chapter 5 on the Inversion of Control Container.

Comment: Btw: if you use the default scopes of spring beans the creation happens at startup / deployment. Only the injection will happen at runtime.
The default scope of spring beans is singleton